# How to reproduce error: "[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sockets, mocking

I have some code which uses some library to deal with API of some web service, which in turn uses httplib, which uses socket, and socket sometimes gives the customer following stacktrace:

```
File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1027, in getresponse 
   response.begin()
File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
   version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
   line = self.fp.readline()
File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
   data = recv(1)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

How to reproduce it intentionally, so I could test code which handles it? I am thinking that unittest with test case which mocks readline method in socket library, but which exception should i throw from that mocked method?

**UPD**: Looks like it should be:

```
raise socket.error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

The question left: "Now how should I mock socket library?".

Comment: I'm getting the same exact thing on twitter firehouse...